# Removing Comma From Javascript Split

Tags: javascript

I made this quick test to remove '/wtv7q/' in this example, but when the alert appears it includes a ","

What's the simplest option to remove this comma?

```
var test = window.location.pathname.split('/wtv7q/');
alert(test);
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/wtv7q/2/

Comment: `.join ('')` ? *(`test` is an array)*

Comment: Or even [`.replace("/wtv7q/","")`](http://jsfiddle.net/wtv7q/3/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` returns an array. To get it back as a string, use `join`:

```
var test = window.location.pathname.split('/wtv7q/').join('');
alert(test);
```

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps:

```
var url="http://jsfiddle.net/wtv7q/6/";
 var test = url.split('/wtv7q/').join("");
  alert(test);
```

Here is the working example:  http://jsbin.com/horuriso/5/edit